# Screen Sharing a Single Application

Tags: xorg, vnc, rdp, display-manager

I'm curious if there is a way to share a single application window with another machine without sharing my entire desktop? Perhaps there is some way to virtually create a new display and place my application in there and share this over VNC or RDP.

I haven't be able to find any existing solutions to this problem and am happy to hack around to come up with something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is called application virtualization.

Most teleconference tools allow sharing of only one app and allow the users to interact with that app.

I often use Google Hangouts to share a single application window:

1. Hover over the left side of the video call window, and a bar with
   various app icons will appear.
2. Click [image] Screenshare on the left
   side of your screen.
3. In the window that appears, choose your desktop or choose the window
   you want to share.
4. Click Start Screenshare.

[Source](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1660627?hl=en)